# Can't post images?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, images

Whenever I try to add an image to a question on Google Chrome, this happens.

[image]

I can't access the button to actually post the question.

I have to switch to Firefox to add images.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Are you unable to drag and drop (or click) for the upload dialog?

Comment: Which add-ons, if any, do you have installed? If

Comment: @JackBNimble I can drag and drop, but then I can't actually post the image.

Comment: @CreationEdge None.

Comment: Chrome version #?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Are you saying that after choosing an image you can't access the "Post Your Question/Answer" buttons? Or merely that clicking the "Drag and drop or click here" button has no effect?

Comment: @RogueJedi After dragging and dropping, is it possible for you to click the "Add Picture" button in the bottom right of the popup (which doesn't appear in your cropped screenshot)?

Comment: @rand I didn't crop the bottom of the image. The website won't let me scroll down any further.

Comment: What's your resolution set at?

Comment: @CreationEdge 35.0.1916.114. I can't currently update Chrome on the computer with the issue, which may be the problem.

Comment: @RogueJedi Possibly, hard to say. My current version is 48...! So, yours being out-of-date might be a cause. What type of device is this on?

Comment: @CreationEdge MacBook Air.

Comment: There have been scrolling issues with Macs and Chrome in previous issues, relating to an underlying problem in the Mac OS. Newer version of Chrome seem to have worked around this, and/or Apple fixed it. You should try and see if it's a problem on any other sites, or just SE.

Comment: @RogueJedi we only support the 2 latest major versions of each browser

Comment: @m0sa Alright, thanks.